# Power analysis for correlations, controlling for multiple comparisons

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, bonferroni

I want to estimate number of participants required for an experiment. I will be conducting 28 correlation tests. I am seeking 80% power for an effect size of 0.15 and alpha of 0.05 (all two-tailed).

Given the number of tests, I want to apply a multiple test correction and still achieve the desired power.

Doing that for Bonferroni is straightforward enough, I believe: my adjusted p-value would be 0.05/28 = 0.0018. Using this p-value I can now estimate that for the desired paramters above; the sample size I need is 691 (calculated using GPower 3.1).

Now, because the Bonferroni adjustment is quite restrictive, I would prefer to use the Benjamini-Hochberg one, but I am unsure how to apply it. After looking through a few papers with complicated computations, I stumbled upon this `R` package, `pwrFDR` (see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pwrFDR/versions/2.8.9/topics/pwrFDR)), that simplifies the job.

I used the following specification for the main `pwrFDR` function, attempting to get the sample size.

```
pwrFDR(effect.size=0.15, average.power=0.80, N.tests=28, r.1 = 10/28,alpha=0.05, FDP.control.method='BHFDR')
```

The suggest sample size from this is 959. Even if I use the highest (and unrealistic) possible `r.1` (proportion of significant tests, if I understand correctly), say 27/28, I still get an estimated sample size of 755, which is higher the one calculated using the Bonferroni procedure.

Given that the Bonferroni method has been shown to have significantly lower power than the Benjamini-Hochberg correction, why do the above estimates show that I need fewer participants with the Bonferroni correction? I think it's likely that I am misunderstanding the `pwrFDR` function specifically, and power analysis using the BH procedure in general.

Comment: If these correlations concern all possible pairs of eight variables, then neither of your approaches is appropriate due to the strong, complex dependencies among the tests. One reliable way to obtain the power curve is through simulation.  Exactly how to do that depends on the specific correlation tests you are conducting.

Comment: @whuber you are correct in that I am correlating all pairs of 8 variables but I cannot figure out why that would be an issue. I appreciate that 1) the amount of tests inflates Type I errors (hence my desire to use an adjustment procedure) and 2) that I might very well be capturing substantial noise, which is a limitation I am willing to endure as this is supposed to be exploratory... And I am not sure I understand why the specific type of correlation test would make a difference: I am still testing a hypothesis (that the correlation is different from 0).

Comment: One simple-minded but effective way to think of the situation is to note that only 8 variables are involved but you estimate 28 correlation coefficients.  Those coefficients are thereby pretty strongly interdependent.  How, exactly, do you propose to adjust the 28 resulting p-values?  Treating them as 28 independent values would give quite the wrong answer--but so would treating them as only 8 independent values.  *How* to adjust them depends on the dependence structure; and that in turn relates to how you estimate the coefficients.